# AWS Lambda Duration vs Function run time

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless-framework

I noticed a duration vs function run time issue in Cloud watch log with my Nodejs Lambda function. I am using Serverless plugin to deploy/code my functions.

This is my lambda function code:

```
module.exports.handler = function (event, context, cb) {
    console.time("function_run_time");
    myFunction(function (callback) {
       console.timeEnd("function_run_time");
       return cb(null, callback)
    });
};
```

In cloud watch logs Im getting the following

```
2016-05-25T00:18:58.881Z    45cd0785-ccce-11e6-818f-cb61404e173c    function_run_time: 477ms 
REPORT RequestId: 45cd0785-ccce-11e6-818f-cb61404e173c  Duration: 1866ms    Billed Duration: 1900 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB   Max Memory Used: 39 MB
```

I am wondering why the function run time is at 477ms however the duration is at 1866ms.

Is there something in my code I need to call to end the Lamdba function earlier?

Thanks

Comment: The time should reduce on subsequent invocation. The overhead is spent by lamda is allocating a container for execution of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have code running after you are calling callback
See here: [aws lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html#nodejs-prog-model-context-methods)

> By default, the callback will wait until the Node.js runtime event loop is empty before freezing the process and returning the results to the caller. You can set this property to false to request AWS Lambda to freeze the process soon after the callback is called

Also if you are using an [older version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-using-old-runtime.html) of node with Lambda you should call 
`context.succeed();` and `context.fail(error)` to end the function.

Comment: Thanks for your input, the duration has reduced after running the function a few times. But I will take a look at what you suggested!